# Angular gives an error when use safe navigation operator

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used a `safe navigation operator` in my code.

[image]

But angular gives an error when I execute the code.

[image]

[image]

Why this error: Because `typescript` takes it's a ternary operator `?::` but I used it as a
`safe navigation operator`.
So how to solve this Issue?

version:
"typescript": `~2.9.2`,
Angular: `6`

Comment: what typescript version you're using in your angular project?

Comment: "typescript": "~2.9.2"

Comment: Note that `Optional chaining` only  supported as of TypeScript 3.7 or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) `Optional chaining` only supported as of `TypeScript 3.7` or later.

So you need to update your typescript version or use traditional way of checking null:

```
if($event && $event.actionField && $event.actionField.toLowerCase()=="..."){}
```